# How to include a custom footer on the bottom of every page in org mode export?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export

How would I create a footer on the bottom of every page? Ideally, I wish I could just add:

```
 #+FOOTER: Confidential.
```

And then it would include it. How easy would it be to do that? Otherwise, is there another way to do this? Right now I'd be happy with this just working when exporting to PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fancyhdr}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \pagestyle{fancyplain}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \chead{Companies Act 2012 - Memorandum and Articles of Association}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \lhead{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \rhead{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \cfoot{GOLDIVANTI GOLD LIMITED}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \lfoot{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \rfoot{}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in PDF, add LaTeX options

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
```

Then set one or more of `\lhead{}`, `\chead{}`, `\rhead{}`, `\lfoot{}`, `\cfoot{}`, or `\rfoot{}`.

Comment: I know what to do with `fancyhdr`, but could you give an example line for using `\pagestyle` and `\lfoot{}`?

Comment: `\lfoot{Confidential}`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean what does the associated org-mode markup look like?

Comment: e.g.  `#+LATEX_OPTION: \lfoot{Confidential.}`

Comment: The option `#:LATEX_OPTION` doesn't actually exist.

Comment: #+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA: \some_latex_command